# Message received by app when user click on top bar

Tags: c, linux, x11, wine

I understand that the window manager send a WM_DELETE_WINDOW when a user click on X button on top bar.

But if user just click on the top bar , without to click the minimize , maximize and X buttons ?Is there a message wine receive if user just click the top bar ? Of if the user move the window ,clicking and dragging on top bar ?
What message wine receive if user just click on a free space on top bar?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If the application is not the current one, the window should get a FocusIn event (and FocusOut if another application is selected) when you click the top bar. If it already is at the foreground, I don't know; probably nothing.

Moving and resizing are handled by ConfigureNotify events.

Comment: Very interesting . Thanks for tips